# Issues with hover and transitions in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am having issues with the code attached in Firefox & IE. I'm not sure where to even start to fix the issue. If you view the code in Chrome, everything works perfectly fine, but it's really messed up in Firefox.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```css
 
 .empty_canvas_content {
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 }
 
 *{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
 .containerclaims{margin:0 auto;max-width:1140px;}
 [class*=bit-]{float:left;padding:.3em;}
 
 /* Grids */
 .bit-1{width:100%;}
 .bit-2{width:50%;}
 .bit-3{width:33.33333%;}
 .bit-4{width:25%;}
 .bit-5{width:20%;}
 .bit-6{width:16.66667%;}
 .bit-7{width:14.28571%;}
 .bit-8{width:12.5%;}
 .bit-9{width:11.11111%;}
 .bit-10{width:10%;}
 .bit-11{width:9.09091%;}
 .bit-12{width:8.33333%;}
 .bit-25{width:25%;}
 .bit-40{width:40%;}
 .bit-60{width:60%;}
 .bit-75{width:75%;}
 .bit-35{width:35%;}
 .bit-65{width:65%;}
 
 /* Hover Effect */
 .hovereffect {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: default;
   background: #000;
 }

 .hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 45%;
   left: 0;
   text-align: center;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

 .hovereffect img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   max-width: none;
   width: calc(100% + 20px);
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
   transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
 }

 .hovereffect:hover img {
   opacity: 0.5;
   filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }

 .hovereffect h2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0px 20px black, 0 0 0px black;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 17px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0.5em 0;
   background-color: transparent;
 }
 
 /*.hovereffect h2:after {
   position: absolute;
 text-shadow: none;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   background: #fff;
 content: '';
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
   transition: transform 0.35s;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 }*/

 .hovereffect:hover h2:after {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }

 .hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {
   color: #FFF;
   opacity: 0;
 margin-top:-30px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
   transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 }

 .hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p {
   opacity: 1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
 /* End Hover Effect */
 
 /* Button */
 .HomepageBtn {
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:15px;
 width:200px;
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 12px;
   background: #000;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .HomepageBtn:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .hideformobile {display:block;}
 .showformobile {display:none;}
 
 
 /* Responsive Goodness */
 /* Defaults above are set Desktop resolution or higher */
 
 /* Laptop */
 @media (min-width:50em) and (max-width:68.75em){
 .bit-7,.bit-35,.bit-65{width:100%;}
 .bit-10,.bit-12,.bit-4,.bit-8{width:50%;}
 }
 
 /* Tablet */
 @media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em){
 .bit-10,.bit-12,.bit-4,.bit-6,.bit-8{width:50%;}
 .bit-1,.bit-11,.bit-3,.bit-5,.bit-7,.bit-9{width:100%;}
 }
 
 /* Mobile */
 @media (max-width:40em){
 .bit-1,.bit-10,.bit-11,.bit-12,.bit-2,.bit-3,.bit-4,.bit-5,.bit-6,.bit-7,.bit-8,.bit-9{width:100%;}
 .hideformobile {display:none;}
 .showformobile {display:block;}
 }
```

```html
<p>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <div class="containerclaims">
        <div class="hideformobile">
            <div class="bit-1">
                <picture> <source media="(min-width: 50em)" srcset="//deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/header?wid=1200&amp;fmt=jpg" width="100%"></source> <source media="(min-width: 0em)" srcset="//deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/header-mobile-3?wid=1219&amp;fmt=jpg" width="100%"></source> <!-- img tag for browsers that do not support picture element --> <img src="//deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/header?wid=1200&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="Get More. Save More." width="100%" /> </picture>
                <p style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:1px; text-align:center; font-size:12px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular'; color: #979797; text-decoration:none !important;"><a href="/women-shoes.cat?source=hpheaderwomens--desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall">SHOP MEN'S &rarr;</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/girls-shoes.cat?source=hpheadergirls-desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall">SHOP GIRLS' &rarr;</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/boys-shoes.cat?source=hpheaderboys-desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall">SHOP BOYS' &rarr;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bit-1">
            <div class="bit-2">
                <div class="hideformobile">
                    <div class="hovereffect"><a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-combatlaceup.cat?source=hpstory1desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story1?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a>
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2 style="font-size:40px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration:none !important;">Lace Up</h2>
                            <p><a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-combatlaceup.cat?filter-cat=%2Fhighlight%2Fwomen-shoes%2Fwomen-boots%2Fwomen-boots-combatlaceup&amp;pp=40&amp;orderby=price-asc?source=hpstory1pricepoint&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular'; font-weight:400; color:#fff; text-decoration:none !important;">STARTING AT $34.99</font></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="showformobile"><a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-combatlaceup.cat?source=hpstory1mobile&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story1?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
                <div class="bit-1" style="margin-top:12px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    <div class="showformobile"><center><font style="font-size:25px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">Women's Lace Up</font><br />
                            <p style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:-5px;"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; letter-spacing:2px;">STARTING AT <font style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', sans-serif;">$34.99</font></font></p>
                        </center></div>
                    <center><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">A fall frontrunner, fit to be tied. Available in a variety of heights and styles, you're sure to find a pair for any occasion.</font> <a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-combatlaceup.cat?source=hpstory1shopnow&amp;icid=20161019_fall">
                            <div class="HomepageBtn">SHOP NOW &rarr;</div>
                        </a> </center></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bit-2">
                <div class="hideformobile">
                    <div class="hovereffect"><a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-bootiesankleboots.cat?source=hpstory2desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story2?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a>
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2 style="font-size:40px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration:none !important;">Short Boots</h2>
                            <p><a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-bootiesankleboots.cat?filter-cat=%2Fhighlight%2Fwomen-shoes%2Fwomen-boots%2Fwomen-boots-bootiesankleboots&amp;pp=40&amp;orderby=price-asc?source=hpstory2pricepoint&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular'; font-weight:400; color:#fff; text-decoration:none !important;">STARTING AT $29.99</font></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="showformobile"><a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-bootiesankleboots.cat?source=hpstory2mobile&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story2?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
                <div class="bit-1" style="margin-top:12px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    <div class="showformobile"><center><font style="font-size:25px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">Women's Short Boots</font><br />
                            <p style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:-5px;"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; letter-spacing:2px;">STARTING AT <font style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', sans-serif;">$29.99</font></font></p>
                        </center></div>
                    <center><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">Keep it short and sweet with this season's go-to boot. Suitable for any wardrobe with an array of styles to choose from.</font> <a href="/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-bootiesankleboots.cat?source=hpstory2shopnow&amp;icid=20161019_fall">
                            <div class="HomepageBtn">SHOP NOW &rarr;</div>
                        </a> </center></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bit-1" style="margin-bottom:8px;"><a href="#lightboxClickOpen">
                <picture> <source media="(min-width: 50em)" srcset="//deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/video?wid=1200&amp;fmt=jpg" width="100%"></source> <source media="(min-width: 0em)" srcset="//deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/video-mobile?wid=1219&amp;fmt=jpg" width="100%"></source> <!-- img tag for browsers that do not support picture element --> <img src="//deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/video?wid=1200&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="Get More. Save More." width="100%" /> </picture>
            </a></div>
        <div class="bit-1" style="margin-top:25px;">
            <div class="bit-2">
                <div class="hideformobile">
                    <div class="hovereffect"><a href="/men-shoes/men-boots.cat?source=hpstory3desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story3?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a>
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2 style="font-size:40px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration:none !important;">Men's Boots</h2>
                            <p><a href="/men-shoes/men-boots.cat?filter-cat=%2Fhighlight%2Fmen-shoes%2Fmen-boots&amp;pp=40&amp;orderby=price-asc?source=hpstory3pricepoint&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular'; font-weight:400; color:#fff; text-decoration:none !important;">STARTING AT $49.99</font></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="showformobile"><a href="/men-shoes/men-boots.cat?source=hpstory3mobile&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story3?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
                <div class="bit-1" style="margin-top:12px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    <div class="showformobile"><center><font style="font-size:25px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">Men's Boots</font><br />
                            <p style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:-5px;"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; letter-spacing:2px;">STARTING AT <font style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', sans-serif;">$49.99</font></font></p>
                        </center></div>
                    <center><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">Fashion forward style with a gentleman's touch. New styles, plus a dash of detail make these boots anything but ordinary.</font> <a href="/men-shoes/men-boots.cat?source=hpstory3shopnow&amp;icid=20161019_fall">
                            <div class="HomepageBtn">SHOP NOW &rarr;</div>
                        </a> </center></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bit-2">
                <div class="hideformobile">
                    <div class="hovereffect"><a href="/men-shoes/men-boots/men-boots-chukka.cat?source=hpstory4desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story4?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a>
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2 style="font-size:40px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration:none !important;">Men's Chukka</h2>
                            <p><a href="/men-shoes/men-boots/men-boots-chukka.cat?filter-cat=%2Fhighlight%2Fmen-shoes%2Fmen-boots%2Fmen-boots-chukka&amp;pp=40&amp;orderby=price-asc?source=hpstory4pricepoint&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular'; font-weight:400; color:#fff; text-decoration:none !important;">STARTING AT $59.99</font></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="showformobile"><a href="/men-shoes/men-boots/men-boots-chukka.cat?source=hpstory4mobile&amp;icid=20161019_fall"><img src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story4?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
                <div class="bit-1" style="margin-top:12px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    <div class="showformobile"><center><font style="font-size:25px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">Men's Chukka</font><br />
                            <p style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:-5px;"><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; letter-spacing:2px;">STARTING AT <font style="font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', sans-serif;">$59.99</font></font></p>
                        </center></div>
                    <center><font style="font-size:14px; font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#000; text-decoration:none !important;">Foundation of style. Perfect to take from workday to weekend. This updated classic is a versatile choice for anywhere you want to go.</font> <a href="/men-shoes/men-boots/men-boots-chukka.cat?source=hpstory4shopnow&amp;icid=20161019_fall">
                            <div class="HomepageBtn">SHOP NOW &rarr;</div>
                        </a> </center></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I resolved the issue. You can't have a <a href="#"> link wrapped around the <img> tag for some reason. What I ended up doing was adding an onclick event in the image tag it self to load a new page. Below is an example from the code:

Comment: <img class="img-responsive" src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/story1?wid=588&amp;fmt=jpg" alt="" width="100%" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="location.reload();location.href='/women-shoes/women-boots/women-boots-combatlaceup.cat?source=hpstory1desktop&amp;icid=20161019_fall'" />